# Does using sha256 on a password that is passed to a servlet make it vulnerable to brute force attacks?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cryptography

I have a simple login servlet shown below.. passes username and password to a servlet and checks a MySQL DB to verify if username and pwd are available. I want to add a hash like sha256 to the password for security, like this:

```
st.executeQuery("select fname, lname, email from userAccount where Email='"+ email + "' and password='"+ sha256(pwd) + "'");
```

Does this make it vulnerable to dictionary attacks or brute force attacks?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class loginServlet
*/
@WebServlet("/loginServlet")
public class loginServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @seeHttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public loginServlet() {
    super();
    // TODOAuto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @seeHttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 * response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODOAuto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @seeHttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 * response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con =
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logindb",
                "root", "password");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = st.executeQuery("select fname, lname, email from userAccount where Email='"
                + email + "' and password='" + pwd + "'");
        if (rs.next()) {
            session.setAttribute("email", email);
            session.setAttribute("Fullname", rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));
            response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
        } else {

            response.sendRedirect("fail.jsp");
        }
    } catch (Exception ssd) {
        System.out.println(ssd.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is possibly vulnerable for SQL Injection attacks. There are also better choices for hashing passwords than SHA256. If you need safety, use bcrypt or scrypt.